# Is this inequality true? It pops up from my research.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given that $a_1(t), a_2(t), b_1(t), b_2(t) > 0$ are continuously differentiable functions for any $t > 0$. Also suppose $\lim_{t\to \infty} a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 = 0$. Suppose $\int_0^x a_1(t) dt > \int_0^x a_2(t) dt$ and $\int_0^x b_1(t) dt > \int_0^x b_2(t) dt$ for any $x >0$.

Is it true that $\int_0^\infty a_1(t) b_1(t) dt \geq \int_0^\infty a_2(t)b_2(t) dt$? If this it not true, under what additional assumptions will it hold true?

This is problem that pops up in my research. Any thoughts would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: If the $a$'s and $b$'s are functions, please write them as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false. Here is a counterexample, where the assumptions hold (excepted that the inequalities are large: $\ge$ instead of $>$), but the conclusion fails. For example, assume that $a_1(t) = 1+\sin(t)$, $a_2(t) = 1-\sin(t)$, $b_1(t) = b_2(t) = 1_{[\pi,2\pi]}(t) \times \sin^2(t)$.

Comment: What do you mean by a "large" inequality?

Comment: I don’t think your $b_i$ are continuous over the positive reals

Comment: @coffeemath: presumably it means "not strict". Christophe, if so, can you edit please?

Comment: @Aryan Dugar This time, the $b_i$ are $\mathcal{C}^1$.

Comment: This is great. Thank you! Any thoughts about how we can potentially make a fix to it?

Comment: I do not see what additional assumption could ensure the conclusion, excepted $a_1 \le a_2$ and $b_1 \le b_2$ everywhere.

Comment: I think if you assume this equality is true over any interval, then since the derivative of the integral is the function itself, you can get that $a_1 \geq a_2$ and similarly for the $b_i$ at every point - this would then give you your desired claim.

Comment: @Aryan Dugar. Sorry, I meant $a_1 \ge a_2$ and $b_1 \ge b_2$. Inequalities can be integrated, but cannot be derivated.

Comment: You’d have for any finite positive $h$ that $\int_x^{x+h} a_1(t) dt \geq \int_x^{x+h} a_2(t) dt$ - so, $\frac{\int_x^{x+h} a_1(t) dt}{h} \geq \frac{\int_x^{x+h} a_2(t) dt}{h}$, and this must hold in the limit as $h$ approaches 0. But the former evaluates to $a_1(x)$ and the latter to $a_2(x)$. What do you think?

Comment: @Aryan Dugar You can not subtract inequalities, so you do not know what is the greatest of both integrals from $x$ to $x+h$.

Comment: Sorry, which inequalities am I illegally subtracting? I wasn't sure. I also meant that if we assume the initial inequality for integrals over any interval (rather than just $0$ to $x$), then we can do what I am suggesting in my previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140841/discussion-between-christophe-leuridan-and-aryan-dugar).